# ISNOTHING expression with two fields

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create an expression to hide a row on a report when both fields are blank. It is working for one field with

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldA.Value),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I am trying to work out something like

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldA.Value AND Fields!FieldB.Value),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below and let me know is it working for you or not,

```
=IIF(NOT(IsNothing(CStr(Fields!FieldA.Value)) AND IsNothing(CStr(Fields!FieldB.Value))),False,True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Expression

```
=IIF(Fields!FieldA.Value Is Nothing AND Fields!FieldB.Value Is Nothing ,True,False)
```

IsNothing() Function receive one patameter you code send

```
Fields!FieldA.Value AND Fields!FieldB.Value
```

it's invalid parameter if you want to use IsNothing() function try this Expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldA.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!FieldB.Value),True,False)
```